# Automatically confirm Yes to powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell

I know that this question seems familiar in a lot of stackoverflow questions. But This is not the same as the other questions.
Basically i've got a PS script that uses the module "AzSK" to run something , I used this command in a loop to add multiple properties to my azure storage. On every step the command keeps asking me to confirm if i want to continue (Y/N).
Because I use a loop for more than 40 iterations I need to confirm every time I perform the command. 
Like many Stackoverflow questions and the internet told me i need to try to add -Force , -Confirm to my command to automatically confirm the yes to the read input. But this answer only applies to commands that have this parameter build in. with the get-help command -Detailed I didn't see any of this parameter available. So I was wondering if it was possible to create this auto "Y" reply even if the command does not allow any parameter for it.

The command I use is `Get-AzSKAzureServicesSecurityStatus` and this adds attestation statuses to control id inside a azure blob storage. the command only allows one attestation status to be added so I wrapped it inside a for loop. Which makes my struggle of constantly confirmation even worse.

Comment: When you say you have used `-Confirm`, did you use it as `-Confirm:$false`? This is generally how the `-Confirm` parameter is used in order to prevent prompts, and I just want to confirm.

Comment: The other thing: Get-* cmdlets generally aren't causing change, so are you sure there isn't a different command prompting? You said you are using this command "in a loop to add multiple properties to my azure storage." Get-* cmdlets wouldn't be causing change, so I think you are looking at the wrong cause of your prompt. Should probably include an example of your code.

Comment: Hi achahbar, have you solved the issue? does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an answer to your query `"if it was possible to create this auto "Y" reply even if the command does not allow any parameter for it."`
But since you are trying it specifically for the attestation feature of the [Secure DevOps Kit for Azure(AzSK)](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit), this might help:

The reason the confirmation message pops up for **each** control and does not allow a "Forced" yes is because:

> Utmost discretion is to be used when attesting controls using the
>   Secure DevOps Kit for Azure(AzSK). In particular, when choosing to not
>   fix a failing control, you are taking accountability that nothing will
>   go wrong even though security is not correctly/fully configured.

Ideally, the bulk attestation feature is meant to be used in case the **same** control needs to be attested across multiple resource instances/resource groups and not vice versa. Refer [this](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/blob/master/00c-Addressing-Control-Failures/Readme.md#bulk-attestation) for scenarios where this feature can be used (although not recommended).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thnx for the effort. I think i am going to close this issue because indeed for security reasons this may not be even possible in Azsk. Your link however is already the way i am using to add bulk attestation statusses.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use the format below:

```
cmd /c echo y | powershell "the command which will propmt"
```

I did a simple test which to delete a directory, and works.

[image]

Comment: As this seems promising , saddly this doesn't work. I get this error 
`powershell : Get-AzSKAzureServicesSecurityStatus : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'check'powershell : Get-AzSKAzureServicesSecurityStatus : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'check' `

Comment: Can you post some dummy code so that I can test it at my side?

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/MAoRX 
This is a command from the module Azsk (import-module AzSK) 
Doc: https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs

Comment: Hi @achahbar, where did you run the scripts? locally or somewhere?

Comment: i runned them on my locally