# how to automatically answer Yes to multiple prompt in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to automatically answer multiple 'Yes' on below command
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force -Confirm:$false

I checked below url and it only answer one y, but trying to add 2 'y' as below, it does not work.
is there any method we can make it ?

cmd /c echo y y| powershell "the command which will propmt"

[Automatically confirm Yes to powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035744/automatically-confirm-yes-to-powershell-script)

Answer (score 7):

**From PowerShell**:

```
, 'y' * 2  | powershell -c 'read-host one; read-host two'
```

`, 'y' * 2` constructs a 2-element array consisting of `'y'` strings (the equivalent of `'y', 'y'`).

**Used as pipeline input** for an external program (which happens to be another PowerShell process in this case), **PowerShell sends each element followed by a newline**, which each answers one prompt in the PowerShell code.

---

**From `cmd.exe`**:

```
(echo y& echo y) | powershell -c "read-host one; read-host two"
```

Note: The **use of `(...)` in a pipeline apparently invariably appends a space to each `echo` command's output**, so that each prompt in PowerShell receives `'y <Enter>'`; this shouldn't be a problem, but if it is, you can use an intermediate temporary file:
`(echo y& echo y) >tmp.txt & type tmp.txt | powershell ... & del tmp.txt`

Comment: thanks a great @mklement0 for the detailed explanation