# Is there a way to bypass the Power-Shell confirmation(Y/N) prompt in Azure Automation Runbook

Tags: azure-automation

Is there a way to bypass the PowerShell cmdlet's confirmation prompt (Yes/No) in Azure Automation Runbook.

Using `ECHO Y | powershell` worked fine locally, but not in Azure Automation.

**Below is the error**

*The term 'PowerShell' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

Tried with the `ECHO Y | pwsh` as well.

Any suggestions or advice will be appreciated.

```
# Attestation
foreach ($inputItem in $inputContents) {
    
    $ControlID = $inputItem.ControlID
    $ResourceName = $inputItem.ResourceName
    $AttestationStatus = $inputItem.AttestationStatus
    $JustificationText = $inputItem.JustificationText

    try {
        echo Y | powershell Get-AzSKAzureServicesSecurityStatus -SubscriptionId $RunAsConnection.SubscriptionId `
            -ResourceNames $ResourceName `
            -ControlsToAttest NotAttested `
            -ControlId $ControlID `
            -AttestationStatus $AttestationStatus `
            -JustificationText $JustificationText

            Write-Host "INFO: Completed the attestation for $ResourceName"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "ERROR: Could not attest the resource $ResourceName due to error $_ "
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can bypass the confirmation in various ways as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7). The easiest and safest way can be recommended if you share more context on what your runbook is trying to accomplish.

**UPDATE 2**:
Thanks for providing additional context around the issue. As the issue is related to AzSK which by default doesn't accept above mentioned -Confirm / -Force, etc. so I have raised [this](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/issues/362) feature request with maintainers of the AzSK. Please check it for future updates on it.

Also, check response from khushboo in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035744/) question which explains regarding related issue.

Comment: We are using the AzSK PowerShell module to check the security of the Azure resources. 
[Link](https://azsk.azurewebsites.net/)
The job runs every three hours and provides a security report.
If there is a security leak (Ex: AlwaysOn is not enabled for the web app) 
We need to manually fix the thing or we need to attest the resources by using "WillFixLater, NotAnIssue".
For the attestation, we are thinking to use an azure automation runbook. 
But here is the issue, the attestation initiates where the user is prompted to continue attestation with a ‘Yes/No’ option.

Comment: I was able to bypass this `Yes/No` prompt by using `ECHO Y | PowerShell` locally. 
But it is not working with the azure automation runbook.

Comment: FYI, the module doesn't have a Force/Confirm switch.

Comment: Updated the initial ask with a runbook code for your reference

Comment: Thanks for sharing the runbook. Updated the above answer with additional information under UPDATE 2 section.